# Prove that if $ab > 0$, then $a$ and $b$ are either both positive or both negative

Tags: calculus, real-numbers

This is an exercise from Tom Apostol's *Calculus*, and what I'm trying to do is to prove from the field and order axioms that if $a > 0$ then $b > 0$, and if $a < 0$ then $b < 0$, since I have already proved that $a$ and $b$ can't be $0$ by theorem 1.11 given in the book.

I have seen someone suggest proving it by contradiction. However, I would like to prove it directly. I have found a solution from a blog, but I don't understand how does $a(-b) < 0$ imply that $-b < 0$. I have also thought about using axiom 7 to prove that $ab(\frac{1}{a}) = b$ is positive if $a$ is positive, but I would need to prove that $\frac{1}{a}$ is positive if $a$ is positive, and I also get stuck there. I will leave an image of the solution I found and another of the axioms.
[Theorem 1,11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a3WI.png)
[Blog solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4z5mk.png)
[Order axioms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf3us.png)

Comment: Do you have a theorem telling you that the product of two positive numbers is positive?

Comment: I think you might be making a mistake when you say that Theorem 1.11 shows that $a$ and $b$ must be nonzero. Can you have a closer look and try to identify your mistake?

Comment: @Anonymous No, that's correct.  Since the product of $0$ with anything must be $0$, it follows that $ab \neq 0 \Rightarrow a, b \neq 0$.

Comment: @RobertShore Have you looked at what Theorem 1.11 says?

Comment: @RobertShore Yes, it's the axiom 7 If x and y are in R+, so are x + y and xy.

Comment: @Anonymous Now I see your point.  You need to prove from the field axioms that $0a=a \forall a \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: @RobertShore well, there is a theorem that states that 0*a=a*0=0, so I guess that counts

Comment: @Santiago Yes, if you already have that theorem, that's the one to use.

Comment: To argue directly rather than by contradiction, you probably need to know something about the sign of $a^{-1}$ given the sign of $a$. But there don't seem to be any theorems on this before I.24, which is what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @Anonymous Right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Exercise 1 in I 3.5 asking you to prove Theorem I.24, and you are permitted to use earlier theorems and axioms.

Firstly, your argument to prove that $a$ and $b$ are nonzero is incorrect. This follows directly from one of the earlier theorems, but not from Theorem I.11 as you say. Can you identify the right one?

Next, assume for a contradiction that $a$ and $b$ are not both positive or both negative, that is that they have opposite signs. For example, since $a$ and $b$ play similar roles, we may assume that $a > 0$ and $b < 0$. (When I say that $a$ and $b$ play similar roles, I am relying on the fact that $ab = ba$.)

Now you can apply Theorem I.19 to the inequality $b < 0$, multiplying by $a$, which is positive. (We again need the same earlier theorem here.) This will yield a contradiction, proving what you want.

The reason a proof by contradiction is best, in my opinion, is that it avoids introducing consideration of inverses. In other words, you make certain assumptions about the signs of $a$ and $b$, and you determine the sign of $ab$. What really matters here are the cases where $ab$ is negative. Since your assumption is $ab > 0$, this means you must argue by contradiction.

More precisely, you are proving the contrapositive of the original statement, but this is a technicality.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $b \lt 0 \lt a.$  Then $0 \lt -b$ by Axiom $8$, so $a(-b) \gt 0$ by Axiom $7$.

$ab+a(-b)=a(b+(-b))=a(0)=0$, so $a(-b) \gt 0 \Rightarrow ab \lt 0$ by Axiom $7$.

As Anonymous correctly points out, showing that $\forall a \in \Bbb R~(0a=0)$ is the converse of Theorem I.$11$, so you can't use the Theorem to prove it.  You need to prove it from the field axioms.  To prove $0a=a$, note that $0a=(0+0)a=0a+0a \Rightarrow 0=-(0a)+0a=(-(0a)+0a)+0a=0+0a=0a$.

Comment: 'ab+a(−b)=a(b+(−b))=a(0)=0, so a(−b)>0⇒ab<0 by Axiom 7.' I don't understand this part. Didn't you already get that a(-b)>0? How come ab<0 by axiom 7?

Comment: Because you know that $ab \neq 0$, and if $ab \gt 0$, then you have $0$ as the sum of two positive numbers, $ab$ and $a(-b)$  Axioms $7$ and $9$ tell you that can't happen.

Comment: Oh, I understand